# Flutter gif image to still image

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation

I have a gif image to show in flutter. I want to show it's first frame as a still image. How can I achieve this thing in flutter?

I want to show it as a static image (first frame of gif image).

Comment: if you could provide your gifs ad short videos, then you can use the flutter_thmbnail package to get a thumbnail image of it.

Comment: Can you provide link for that package? I couldn't find it

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail

Comment: I tried it. It's not rendering gif images. Any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CustomPaint` to draw the first frame of GIF and show the custom widget on the screen.

Here are the steps:

1. Create a `XFile` with the GIF file:

   ```dart
   XFile file = XFile('xxx.gif');
   ```
2. Load the `XFile` to `ui.Image`:

   ```dart
    Future<ui.Image> loadImage(XFile file) async {
     final data = await file.readAsBytes();
     return await decodeImageFromList(data);
   }
   ```
3. Create a custom widget with `CustomPaint` and `CustomPainter`:

   ```dart
    Widget createCustomImage(ui.Image image) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: image.width.toDouble(),
        height: image.height.toDouble(),
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: ImagePainter(image),
        ),
      );
    }

    class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
      ImagePainter(this. Image);
      final ui.Image image;

      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        final paint = Paint()
          ..color = Colors.red
          ..strokeWidth = 5
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

        canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, paint);
      }

      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(ImagePainter oldDelegate) =>
          image != oldDelegate.image;
    }
   ```

A little bit complicated, but it can work.

[image: flutter gif static image]

Comment: XFile definition?

Comment: @SoniaEjaz online doc: [XFile](https://pub.dev/documentation/cross_file/latest/cross_file/XFile-class.html)

Comment: @SoniaEjaz you can also try my [sample code](https://github.com/yushulx/flutter_document_scan_sdk/blob/main/example/lib/main.dart). It's not written for your question. You need to add the gif type to the file selector.

Comment: Yes it's kinda helped me to do my task. Thanks for this